# Is it possible to include the cpp-reference.com documentation into clion's quick documentation viewer?

Tags: clion

The provided documentation for the basic c++ packages within clion seems to be very short, and sometimes it is not possible to find any documentation for basic functions like e.g. the tangens function of the math package.
Is it somehow possible to include the offline-version of cppreference.com into clion's doxygen-based documentation viewer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the moment CLion doesn't support such functionality, here's the ticket for that https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-9413.

As workaround, in case you use Linux you can install standard library with documentation, for instance: 
https://packages.debian.org/sid/libstdc++-6-doc
https://packages.debian.org/sid/glibc-doc
After that CLion will have to work with lib-sources which documentation comments.